# Proving ∀x(A(x) ∨ B) → ∀xA(x) ∨ B, with x is not in B, by natural deduction

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

how can prove  ∀x(A(x) ∨ B) → ∀xA(x) ∨ B where x is not in B using natural deduction.

i am not sure how should use for all introduction rule here.

any help wpuld be highly appreciate.

Cheers

Comment: I think you need some variation of the law of excluded middle here. If $B$ is true, then you're done. But if $B$ is _false_ then $A(x)\lor B$ implies $A(x)$.

Comment: What are the rules of the system you have to work with?  there are many different systems of this kind, each with slightly different rules.

Comment: @Hennnin Makholm.  No, LEM is not needed here.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I'm pretty sure the statement isn't valid in intuitionistic first-order logic.  For example (heuristic argument, might not be a full proof) in the topos $\mathbb{R}$, if $A_n = (-\infty, \frac{1}{n})$ and $B = (0, \infty)$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, (A_n \vee B)$ would be $\mathbb{R}$ whereas $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, A_n) \vee B$ would be $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$.  Or, in terms of a computability interpretation: even if you had a computable function which for each $x$ returns a proof of $A(x)$ or a proof of $B$...

Comment: in general you wouldn't be able to compute whether the function ever returns a proof of $B$, or whether it always returns a proof of $A(x)$.

Comment: $\diamond $\Box$^b$

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Fitch style proof system (i.e. One with Introduction and Elimination rules), I would set this up as a proof by contradiction: Assume $\neg (\forall x \ A(x) \lor B)$, use your rules to derive $\neg \forall x \ A(x))$ and $\neg B$, and use those in combination with your $\forall x (A(x) \lor B)$ to derive a contradiction (this should not be hard: from $\neg \forall x \ A(x)$ you should be able to derive $\exists x \neg A(x)$ (this may require its own proof by contradiction), then witness that existential with an $a$ to get $\neg A(a)$, instantiate the universal to get $(A(a) \lor B)$, and combine those two and the $\neg B$ to get the contradiction)

Comment: Example proof: https://pastebin.com/raw/2pZGPusy

Comment: @quelklef Very nice!